# Event Based Monitoring Instead Of Polling In C

Tags: linux, events, daemon, polling

I have a program which run as a "`daemon`" and does polling ( to monitor presence of some files followed by taking some action when not sleeping ).Other wise it sleeps for configurable number of seconds and then again wakes up for polling.

How can I make the `daemon` `event based` instead of `polling` based  ?

My platform is linux rhel 5.4 and compiler is gcc version 4.

Comment: It depends on what exact events your daemon should wake up to process. If it is indeed based on changes to the file system then one option is to use [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) and [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select).

Comment: _@Thanks Kaylum_  Suppose i want to detect the presence of some files in a particular directory ?

Comment: Do you mean detect when files of interest are first created in a particular directory? If so, then `inotify` and `select` is the way to do it.

Comment: _@Thanks Kaylum_ Yes that is very near to my requirement!

Comment: _@kaylum_ Do I need to need use both `inotify` and 'select` ? Can you suggest any link for example ?